# audio playing is not working in react js and getting error while importing audio file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events, jsx

When try to run my this code,

```js
<audio controls>
   <source src="./audio/sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

The audio file was not playing.

Later I tried to do it this way :

```
import sound from './audio/sound.mp3'

<audio controls>
   <source src={sound} type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './notes/c.mp3' in the src

how can I import mp3/wav file in react without error ?

Comment: Did you configure webpack to handle mp3 files? https://tomroth.com.au/react-sound/

Answer (score 0):

import sound from './audio/sound.mp3'

This approach is working fine. Check your mp3 file path correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. When the website compiles it gives me the following error:

Compiled with problems:

```
ERROR in ./src/sound/alarm.mp3 1:0

Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

I've tried by adding the mp3 text in the webpack config and still gives the same issue.